# MariaDB multiple primary keys or values inside a row

Tags: database-design

I'm new to SQL and am trying to store 3 values per row.
First column is a Server ID, second column is a name and third column is a different ID.
The first ID and the name stay the same, but it is possible for the second ID to change. So I want to use `INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY`. But I want it to update if the first and second column are duplicates. Since I will have multiple rows with the same first ID:

```
ID          |         Name           |       ID 2
--------------------------------------------------
123         |         name1          |    23425
123         |         name2          |    125623
123         |         name3          |    4425252
098         |         name1          |    4354356
....
```

As I'm hoping I could make it clear, each server will have multiple entries (hence the first ID staying the same), these entries represent an object. Said object has a name and an ID. Every server has the same objects but with different IDs. Hence name1 also appearing in ID 098, and so on.

How should I create my table? I want that the server id and name as two combined primary keys, which function as one so to say. So if the server is in the table and the object (name) it should be updated rather than inserted.
As said I was thinking of either two primary keys or one primary key and multiple values. So each server id has a list of the objects containing name and id.

Comment: You can never have two primary keys in a table.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not what you want.  You want two tables:

```
create table ids as (
    id int,
    name varchar(255)
);

create table id_pairs as (
    id int,
    id2 int,
    id references ids(id)
);
```

You can then look up the name for the `id` using a `JOIN`.

This process is called *normalization*.  In general, you want to set up your database so you are not storing the same data in multiple places.  Having multiple rows with `id`/`name` just leads to data integrity problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
   ID int,
   Name varchar(255),
   ID2 int,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, Name));
```

That way the first two fields (ID and Name) are unique.

Because you also want Name and ID2 to be unique, you could create another index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_table` ON `table`(Name, ID2);
```

But maybe it's better to create this extra index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idx_table` ON `table`(ID2, Name);
```

The difference is that, if you only know `ID2`, this index can be used to find the `Name` that belongs to it.